# React tutorial: Why does the HTML page shows a blank page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to follow a React tutorial and I can't a simple program work. I can run a React app without a HTML file, but I can't make the HTML to show anything.

Here is the code:

Index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

I did start `npm` and can run an app if I create a `App.js`, but any help to make the HTML work would be appreciated.

In the dev tools console, I get the following error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` for `index.js`

Comment: Are you using create-react-app ?

Comment: The code is correct. If you are using CRA try running npm start. Otherwise run node index.js

Comment: No mention of any errors thrown here. Check node console and browser dev tools console

Comment: I do not see the Hello World at all only a blank page. Maybe it as to do with homepage configuration in the package.json? That's what I'm currently trying to work on.

Comment: Here is the error I get: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: If you are setting up the react app from scratch then you need to do a bit more than just adding it as a dependency . Here is the link to set it up via webpack if you want to do it from scratch - https://dev.to/deadwing7x/setup-a-react-app-with-webpack-and-babel-4o3k . Another easy option is to use CRA - https://create-react-app.dev/ . This is a boilerplate with all the tools configured for you .

Answer (score 1):

use can use create-react-app, first npm i -g create-react-app, secend create-react-app

the reason you see noting it`s you should config babel & webpack for modern applications, but create-react-app is easy to use for base react project